# System.UnauthorizedAccessException on File.OpenRead

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight, and when I try to read a file, and upon reading, the following error occurs:

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Access to the path
>   'C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Camera Roll\WP_20150421_001.jpg' is
>   denied.

```
{
    string filepath = FilePathTextBox.Text;
    string cryptPath = filepath;
    File.SetAttributes(cryptPath, System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal);

    FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(cryptPath);
    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];

    stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    stream.Close();

    byte[] ProtectedFileBytes = ProtectedData.Protect(fileBytes, null);
    using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Data\Users\Public\Documents"))
    {
        file.Write(ProtectedFileBytes, 0, ProtectedFileBytes.Length);
    }
    MessageBox.Show("File Sucessfully Encrypted");
}
```

All of the relevant libraries are checked in the manifest, I'm running Visual Studio as administrator, I've tried different files, all to no avail.

I added a check to verify if the file exists, and that flagged as false, but that is likely due to the permissions problem.

Any suggestions as to solving this problem?



Edit:
I now have this code, which is throwing a System.ArgumentException:

```
private async void EncryptButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string filepath = FilePathTextBox.Text;
        string cryptPath = filepath;

        await FileOps();
            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(cryptPath);
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];

            stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            stream.Close();

            byte[] ProtectedFileBytes = ProtectedData.Protect(fileBytes, null);
            using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Data\Users\Public\Documents"))
            {
                file.Write(ProtectedFileBytes, 0, ProtectedFileBytes.Length);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("File Sucessfully Encrypted");
    }

    private async Task FileOps()
    {
        string filepath = FilePathTextBox.Text;
        string cryptPath = filepath;
        StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.CameraRoll;
        StorageFile file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(cryptPath, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that you cannot simply access by path... You will need to go through the *known* folders:

[KnownFolders class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx)

[Quickstart: Working with files and folders in Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx)

```
// Get the folder.
StorageFolder camera = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.CameraRoll;

if (local != null)
{

    // Get the file.
    var file = await camera.OpenStreamForReadAsync("WP_20150421_001.jpg");

    // Read the data.
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        //streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried accessing the Documents folder, and the Pictures Folder to get files from there, with the same result, would this also apply?

Comment: You also need to update your assembly manifest file to request permission

Comment: @user3279195 Yes, you would use `KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary`

Comment: How would I go about updating the Assembly Manifest?

Comment: @user3279195 Sounded like you did that (`All of the relevant libraries are checked in the manifest`), are you still having issues? (& update to code sample)

Comment: I'm still having issues, although my code is likely incorrect somewhere, I have posted it as an answer, as it won't fit in this comment box.